# In Keycloak, basing a permission on a custom user attribute

Tags: security, keycloak

I am looking into using Keycloak to give some users special permissions.
The permissions will need to have a limited validity.

My current idea is to set special user attributes, for example `ALLOW_PERIOD_1='2022-01-01:2022-02-01'` and `ALLOW_PERIOD_2='2023-01-01:2023-02-01'`

We will add a mapper to add claims based on the user attributes.
In the application the claims in the token will be checked and allowing this user only access in January 2022 or 2023.

I have 2 questions about this:

1. Is this the right way to manage temporary access per user?
   Perhaps there is a simpler way to achieve the same.
2. Is this secure?
   Can a user set its own custom attributes via the Keycloak pages?
   For example, we have added the custom attribute middleName to our registration page by simply adding a form-variable `"user.attributes.middleName"` to the registration form.
   Can any user add `"user.attributes.ALLOW_PERIOD_1=2022-01-01:2030-01-01"` to a POST to one of the keycloak pages and give himeself access?

Thanks for any advice,

Rob

Comment: Is this meant to be used with which type of application (e.g., frontend, backend...)?

Comment: A React frontend icw a Spring Boot backend. Both can verify the claims from the token without contacting a service.
The frontend can adjust the UI based on the permissions and the backend will enforce them in case the frontend is bypassed.

Comment: Why not doing the check validity on the backend instead on keycloak?

Comment: There are multiple backend services and also the frontend should be able to check the permission. Getting this from the JWT token seems like a simple, safe and fast way, so that's why I want to store it in Keycloak